# Detox + Jest - App has not responded to the network requests below

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I am currently setting up Detox for an existing project and running into snags.

I am using Detox + Jest and am receiving an error

```
[Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 1) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":
"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"hello"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForNotNil","args":[]}}]}

That might be the reason why the test "Login Screen should have login fields" has timed out.
```

My setup is 
detox@14.9.1 
jest-circus@24.9.0 
jest@24.9.0 
node@13.3.0 
 
react-native@0.61.5 
xcode@11.3

my package.json has

```
"detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<project>.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<project>.xcworkspace -scheme <project> -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "type": "iPhone X",
          "id": "D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951", 
          "os": "iOS 10.3.1"
        }
      }, 
      "ios.sim.iphone7": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<project>.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<project>.xcworkspace -scheme <project> -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "type": "iPhone 7",
          "id": "E999FB34-1D9E-46DE-94EF-5181489D0D3E"
        }
      }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "e2e/config.json"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "jest-plugin-context/setup",
      "<rootDir>/test/setup.js"
    ],
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
  }
```

init.js

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');
const assignReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/assignReporter');

// Set the default timeout
jest.setTimeout(60000);

detoxCircus.getEnv().addEventsListener(adapter);
detoxCircus.getEnv().addEventsListener(specReporter);
detoxCircus.getEnv().addEventsListener(assignReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  console.log('start init');
  await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
  console.log('end init');
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  console.log('before each in init.js');
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

and my first test

```
describe('Login Screen', () => {
  it('should have login fields', async () => {
    console.log('in unit test');
    await expect(element(by.text('hello'))).toExist();
  });
});
```

If I attempt to use device methods like device.disableSynchronization() or devise.launchApp({params}) the test will stall there and timeout, not moving on.

Any advise or ideas would be a huge help.

UPDATE :

Here are the logs from detox test -c ios.sim.debug --debug-synchronization 200 --loglevel trace --forceExit

```
detox[76606] INFO:  [test.js] configuration="ios.sim.debug" loglevel="trace" debugSynchronization=200 reportSpecs=true DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1576279006528 node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 --forceExit "e2e"
watchman warning:  opendir(/Users/<user>/code/<project>/node_modules/@babel/.plugin-syntax-jsx.MODULES/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /Users/<user>/code/<project> ; watchman watch-project /Users/<user>/code/<project>`

  console.log e2e/init.js:15
    start init

detox[76607] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:52295...
detox[76607] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:52295
detox[76607] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox[76607] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d
detox[76607] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d
detox[76607] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d","role":"tester"},"messag
eId":0}

detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] applesimutils --list --byId D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951 --byType "iPhone X"
detox[76607] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #0] [
  {
    "deviceType" : {
      "name" : "iPhone X",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone X.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X"
    },
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone X",
    "udid" : "D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951",
    "os" : {
      "buildversion" : "17C45",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "name" : "iOS 13.3",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3",
      "version" : "13.3"
    }
  }
]

detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] applesimutils --list --byId D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951 --maxResults 1
detox[76607] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #1] [
  {
    "deviceType" : {
      "name" : "iPhone X",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone X.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X"
    },
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone X",
    "udid" : "D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951",
    "os" : {
      "buildversion" : "17C45",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "name" : "iOS 13.3",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3",
      "version" : "13.3"
    }
  }
]

detox[76607] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBootDevice({ coldBoot: false, deviceId: 'D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951' })
detox[76607] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeUninstallApp({
  deviceId: 'D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951',
  bundleId: '<project>'
})
detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #2] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951 <project>
detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #2] Uninstalling <project>...
detox[76607] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] 
detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] <project> uninstalled
detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951 "/Users/<user>/code/<project>/ios/build/Buil
d/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<project>.app"
detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #3] Installing /Users/<user>/code/<project>/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<project>.app...
detox[76607] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] 
detox[76607] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] /Users/<user>/code/<project>/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<project>.app installed
detox[76607] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeAll()
  console.log e2e/init.js:18
    end init

Login Screen: should have login fields
  console.log e2e/init.js:22
    before each in init.js

detox[76607] INFO:  Login Screen assigned to D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951 {"type":"iPhone X","id":"D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951"}
detox[76607] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_BEFORE_EACH] running test: "Login Screen should have login fields"
detox[76607] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeEach({
  title: 'should have login fields',
  fullName: 'Login Screen should have login fields',
  status: 'running'
})
  console.log e2e/loginScreen.spec.js:7
    in unit test

detox[76607] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance
"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","
args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"hello"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForNotNil","args":[]}}]},"messageId":1}
detox[76607] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=invoke (sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d)
detox[76607] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d)
detox[76607] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":2}
detox[76607] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=currentStatus (sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d)
detox[76607] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d)
Login Screen: should have login fields [FAIL]
detox[76607] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_AFTER_EACH] failed test: "Login Screen should have login fields"
detox[76607] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterEach({
  title: 'should have login fields',
  fullName: 'Login Screen should have login fields',
  status: 'failed',
  timedOut: true
})

detox[76607] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 1) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":
"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"hello"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForNotNil","args":[]}}]}

That might be the reason why the test "Login Screen should have login fields" has timed out.

detox[76607] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterAll()
detox[76607] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=7b41bb7d-70a4-0ea7-e0a8-604f30dbd51d
detox[76607] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
 FAIL  e2e/loginScreen.spec.js (64.646s)
  Login Screen
    ✕ should have login fields (60003ms)

  ● Login Screen › should have login fields

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 60000ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      4 |   });
      5 | 
    > 6 |   it('should have login fields', async () => {
        |   ^
      7 |     console.log('in unit test');
      8 |     await expect(element(by.text('hello'))).toExist();
      9 |     // await expect(element(by.id('loginScreen-username'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(60000);

      at it (loginScreen.spec.js:6:3)
      at Object.describe (loginScreen.spec.js:1:1)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @haxpanel , i was not able to :( i submitted an issue that was closed : https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1803. So I switch to the Appium framework for mobile testing

Comment: Ohh that's bad.. I've managed to find a workaround which is to disable synchronization `await device.disableSynchronization()` and then `waitFor` elements manually.

Comment: I had EXACTLY this. After hours of investigation (and some rage tbh) I finally found. I have a loader with `Animated` that wasn't manually stopped, even though the component did unmount. I changed it to something like this https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/325#issuecomment-335548129 . (Props to this comment for fixing it !). I hope this helps

Comment: @haxpanel can you brief your temporary solution? where did you add "await device.disableSynchronization()".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to make it working by switching from `Debug` to `Release` simulator.

```
  "ios.sim.release": {
    "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/<project>.app",
    "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<project>.xcworkspace -scheme <project> -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "device": {
      "type": "iPhone X",
      "id": "D6C93AA8-0002-4286-BEFA-AA1CC2BB5951", 
      "os": "iOS 10.3.1"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below code in `AppDelegate.m`

```
  NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
  @{
    kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,
    ...
   };
```

to this

```
  BOOL IS_DETOX = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] containsObject: @"-detoxServer"];    //add this line
  NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
  @{
    kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @(!IS_DETOX),   //change this line
    ...
   };
```

Ref : [Disabling SSL pinning when Detox is running](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2611#issuecomment-849967122)